# wordpress load fancybox image array

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

Any idea why the code below is only loading the thumbnail into the fancybox overlay? The image array within `.portfolio-slideshow` is loading in the background fine, it's just not being triggered correctly with fancybox.
Wordpress code:

```
    <a class="fancybox" href="<?php print $slideshow['guid']; ?>" rel="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                the_post_thumbnail();
            }
        ?>

        <div class="portfolio-slideshow">
            <?php
                $slideshow = get_custom_field('portfolio_images:to_array', 'get_post');
                foreach($slideshow as $img) {
            ?>
                <img src="<?php print $img['guid']; ?>" />
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap the array of images in the fancybox link + the `rel` title, this did the trick:

```
<div class="portfolio-slideshow">
    <?php
        $slideshow = get_custom_field('portfolio_images:to_array', 'get_post');
        foreach($slideshow as $img) {
    ?>
            <a class="fancybox" href="<?php print $img['guid']; ?>" rel="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php print $img['guid']; ?>" /></a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<a class="fancybox" href="<?php print $img['guid']; ?>" rel="<?php the_title(); ?>">

<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
?>

<h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
```

Comment: You were doing it the other way around ;)